# msal.js redirects to localhost inside kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, next.js, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I do have a NextJs app using Msal 2for authentication with AzureAD.

Working locally or inside a dokcer-container locally it works just fine, because the container port 3000 is forwarded directly to the host 3000. Logging in and getting redirected to http://localhost:3000 is a non-issue in that scenario.

Now I have deployed this to a Kubernetes cluster into a dev/staging environment with a self-signed-cert and custom domain, one issue arises: It still wants to redirect back to `http://localhost:3000`, although the nginx ingress controller is pointing to `https://machine.domain.eu`

The current series of events is:

1. Open url
2. Automatically open auth popup
3. popup redirects to `login.microsoftonline.com/...`
4. flow tries to redirect back to `http://localhost:3000/#code=xxxxxxx`

What is supposed to happen is:

4. Redirect back to `https://machine.domain.eu`

The current msal config looks like this:

```
export const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "611c5aa6-f7de-4a06-ace7-xxxxxxxxxx",
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/291d05b0-1020-4f36-aac5-xxxxxxxxxxx",
        redirectUri: process.env.HOSTNAME || "http://localhost:3000",            navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: "localStorage", // This configures where your cache will be stored
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false // Set this to "true" if you are having issues on IE11 or Edge
    },
}
```

while `process.env.HOSTNAME` is dynamically supplied through the build pipeline as a variable in the manifest:

```
spec:
  hostname: web-dev
  containers:
    - name: web 
      image: localhost:32000/web
      env:
      - name: NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED
        value: "0"
      - name: BASE_PATH
        value: '/dev'
      - name: HOSTNAME
        value: 'https://machine.domain.eu'
      ports:
      - containerPort: 3000
```

Is there a hook or other entrypoint to intercept this behaviour?
If I remove the localhost redirect Uri from AzureAD, I'm not even getting that far, so my suspicion right now points towards next.js being the culprit for booting up on localhost:3000 inside the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single reason why this failed on my kubernetes environment.

First of all I had set `navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true`, which meant, if the app started internally on `localhost:3000`, it would redirect to this exact url when the response came through.

This also meant, that setting any value to `redirectUri` had no effect.

The second reason this failed was actually my k8s deployment manifest, which specified the image to pull, but not which version. After setting it explicitly to `:latest`, my changes in code immedieatly took effect.

The reason that brought me on this trail was investigating the pods:

```
microk8s kubetl get pods
microk8s kubectl describe pod web-xxxx-xxxxxxx
```

Here I saw an image with a SHA digest in the likes `registry/web@sha256-xxxxxx`

I compared this value to the most up-to-date image of `web` with `docker images --digest`. Here I saw, that the image tagged with `latest`, had a differnt digest `sha256-yyyyyy`

Takeaway:

1. If the response url is different from the requestUrl, set `navigateToLoginRequestUrl` to `false`
2. Make sure, the image you think the container is built upon, is actually the image you think it is.